# $orderby with $filter doesn't seem to work as documented

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to hit the https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users endpoint and I'm running into a problem with pretty much any combination of $filter and $orderby. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#using-filter-and-orderby-in-the-same-query) about this combination say:

1. Properties that appear in $orderby must also appear in $filter.
2. Properties that appear in $orderby are in the same order as in $filter.
3. Properties that are present in $orderby appear in $filter
   before any properties that aren't.

which seems to suggest this is possible. These aren't the real query I'm trying to run but these are the minimum representation. Some examples:

```
$orderby=displayName&$filter=displayName%20eq%20Miriam
$orderby=displayName&$filter=startswith(displayName,'M')
$orderby=displayName&$filter=startsWith(displayName,'M')&$select=displayName
```

but I always get the error:

```
"code": "Request_UnsupportedQuery",
"message": "Sorting not supported for current query."
```

Am I doing this wrong or is this actually not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this, you need to:

1. Select the beta endpoint
2. Add $count=true in the QueryString
3. Add ConsistencyLevel = eventual to the Request headers

In this way you would be able to achieve this and below is the query you can use

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true&$filter=startswith(displayName,'M')&$orderby=displayName
```

**Note:** APIs under the /beta version in Microsoft Graph are subject to change. Use of these APIs in production applications is not supported.

[image]

Please check this [Documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/build-advanced-queries-with-count-filter-search-and-orderby/).